# How would I make cumulus clouds in Blender (preferably using a smoke simulation)?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've tried messing around with the smoke simulations in Blender, but I can't give the smoke the puffy look of a cumulus cloud.

I've seen tutorials showing methods by using displacement and noise, but the result doesn't look very realistic.

Example added below:
[image]

Comment: My advise would be to combine your smoke simulations with some force fields to gather the clouds. Add a noise and a bit of noise strength to them, and you should see an uneven smoke, kind of like a cloud. You have to tweak the setting **a lot** due to clouds IRL are very complex in their shapes and hard to simulate in Blender. Basically, as far as I know, if you want a 100% accurate result, you'd have to copy the behaviors of the atmosphere to some degree.

Comment: Have you tried the cloud generator addon? https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Cloud_Gen

Comment: Answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87240/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-convection-with-a-particle-system